# How can I prevent war libraries slf4j to collide with my project slf4j?

Tags: jetty, war, slf4j

I am trying to deploy the reddog rdap-server  war file into an embedded Jetty in my project. But everytime I am getting this eror:

java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory used in the signature

Problem is, the war file already contains slf4j. Any suggestions?

I tried to change my maven pom to "provider, which didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Use WebAppContext's (which it seems like from your error, and the mention of WebAppClassLoader).

Don't modify the Server or System classes lists on the WebAppContext or the WebAppClassLoader.

Don't set the WebAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(boolean) field.

That's it.

Now you have the ClassLoader Isolation you are looking for.